# Setting UITextField Text

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios, uitextfield

I have two views in my application handled by my `RootViewController` and `AccountInfoViewController`.

My `AccountInfoViewController` looks like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Account.h"

@interface AccountInfoViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UITextField *acctName;
    IBOutlet UITextField *acctBalance;
    Account *acct;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *acctName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *acctBalance;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Account *acct;

-(void) saveAccountInfo;

@end
```

In my `RootViewController` I am doing this:

```
- (void)editAcctInfo:(Account *)acct {
    if (self.acctInfoViewController == nil) {
        AccountInfoViewController *a = [[AccountInfoViewController alloc]
                                        initWithNibName:@"AccountInfoViewController" 
                                        bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        self.acctInfoViewController = a;
        [a release];
    }

   if (acct != nil ) {
       self.acctInfoViewController.acct = acct;
   }

    //Hide Toolbar
    [toolbar removeFromSuperview];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.acctInfoViewController 
                                         animated:YES];
}
```

Here is my `viewDidLoad` method of my `AccountInfoViewController`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UIBarButtonItem *saveButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Save" 
                                                                   style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                                  target:self 
                                                                  action:@selector(saveAccountInfo:)];
    acctBalance.text = acct.balance.accessibilityValue;
    acctName.text = acct.name.accessibilityValue;
    //acctName.text = @"Test Text";

    self.title =@"Edit Account";
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = saveButton;
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

When I run this, I get nothing in my `UITextFields` of my view.  If I uncomment the line with the "Test Text", that appears fine in my view so I know I have part of it right. 
When debugging, I can see the values under acct.  When I actually hover over the word acct in the code, I get "Invalid Summary" for all the values.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong or if there is a better way to accomplish this? I know it must be a problem with how I am setting the "acct" property in my `AccountInfoViewController`.

This is how I call the above `editAcctInfo` method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    Account *account = [accountTableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [self editAcctInfo:account];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see where you alloc and init your account. You have only declared it in the code you're showing. Is it allocated in your `RootViewController`? is

```
if (acct != nil ) {
   self.acctInfoViewController.acct = acct;
}
```

getting called?

Comment: It is passed in the method call.- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    
    Account *account = [accountTableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    
    [self editAcctInfo:account];
    
}